# get dataframe row count based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the count of dataframe rows based on conditional selection. I tried the following code.

```
print df[(df.IP == head.idxmax()) & (df.Method == 'HEAD') & (df.Referrer == '"-"')].count()
```

output:

```
IP          57
Time        57
Method      57
Resource    57
Status      57
Bytes       57
Referrer    57
Agent       57
dtype: int64
```

The output shows the count for each an every column in the dataframe. Instead I need to get a single count where all of the above conditions satisfied? How to do this? If you need more explanation about my dataframe please let me know.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You are asking for the condition where all the conditions are true,
so len of the frame is the answer, unless I misunderstand what you are asking

```
In [17]: df = DataFrame(randn(20,4),columns=list('ABCD'))

In [18]: df[(df['A']>0) & (df['B']>0) & (df['C']>0)]
Out[18]: 
           A         B         C         D
12  0.491683  0.137766  0.859753 -1.041487
13  0.376200  0.575667  1.534179  1.247358
14  0.428739  1.539973  1.057848 -1.254489

In [19]: df[(df['A']>0) & (df['B']>0) & (df['C']>0)].count()
Out[19]: 
A    3
B    3
C    3
D    3
dtype: int64

In [20]: len(df[(df['A']>0) & (df['B']>0) & (df['C']>0)])
Out[20]: 3
```

Comment: Which one is faster?
```len(df[(df['A']>0)])```
or
```sum(df['A']>0)```?

Comment: no need to wrap with another `df`, just anding the masks should suffice: `((df['A']>0) & (df['B']>0) & (df['C']>0)).sum()`

Comment: Note: in Pandas, `count()` excludes nulls.

Answer (score 29):

In Pandas, I like to use the `shape` attribute to get number of rows.

```
df[df.A > 0].shape[0]
```

gives the number of rows matching the condition `A > 0`, as desired.

Answer (score 20):

For increased performance you should not evaluate the DataFrame using your predicate. Better just use `sum(predecate)` directly as illustrated below:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
 

In [2]: df.head()
Out[2]:
          A         B         C         D
0 -2.019868  1.227246 -0.489257  0.149053
1  0.223285 -0.087784 -0.053048 -0.108584
2 -0.140556 -0.299735 -1.765956  0.517803
3 -0.589489  0.400487  0.107856  0.194890
4  1.309088 -0.596996 -0.623519  0.020400

In [3]: %time sum((df['A']>0) & (df['B']>0))
CPU times: user 1.11 ms, sys: 53 µs, total: 1.16 ms
Wall time: 1.12 ms
Out[3]: 4

In [4]: %time len(df[(df['A']>0) & (df['B']>0)])
CPU times: user 1.38 ms, sys: 78 µs, total: 1.46 ms
Wall time: 1.42 ms
Out[4]: 4
```

Keep in mind that this technique only works for counting the number of rows that comply with your predicate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and get the [`shape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) of the resulting dataframe. For example:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  x
1  2  2  y
2  3  3  z

df.query("A == 2 & B > 1 & C != 'z'").shape[0]
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: I'm a bit late but have a similar issue : If I am looping over a column values, then will this method work by comparing that variable with some value?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'title': ['Manager', 'Technical Analyst', 'Software Engineer', 'Sales Manager'], 'Description': [
'''a man or woman who controls an organization or part of an organization,a person who looks after the business affairs of a singer, actor, etc''',
'''Technical analysts, also known as chartists or technicians, employ technical analysis in their trading and research. Technical analysis looks for price patterns and trends based on historical performance to identify signals based on market sentiment and psychology.''',
'''A software engineer is a person who applies the principles of software engineering to design, develop, maintain, test, and evaluate computer software. The term programmer is sometimes used as a synonym, but may also lack connotations of engineering education or skills.''',
'''A sales manager is someone who leads and supervises sales agents and runs the day-to-day sales operations of a business. They oversee the sales strategy, set sales goals, and track sales performance'''
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data2 = {'title': ['Manager', 'Technical Analyst', 'Software Engineer', 'Sales Manager'], 'Keywords': [
['organization','business','people','arrange']
,['technicians','analysis','research','business']
,['engineering', 'design', 'develop', 'maintain']
,['supervises', 'agents','business','performance','target']
]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)
df2=df2.explode('Keywords')

print(df2)
print("checking df3")
df3=df.merge(df2,how='left',on='title')
print(df3)
df3['match'] = df3.apply(lambda x: x.Keywords in x.Description, axis=1)
print(df3)
df4=df3.loc[df3['match']==True].groupby(['Description']).count()
print(df4)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).