# Count the number of values that satisfy a condition in every column of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several columns of data.  In the data, a -1 is equivalent to missing data.  I want to count the number of -1 values in each column.

I believe I could register -1 as a NaN/missing value when I load the data and then I saw something that used isna() and counted boolean values.  However, what I want to do (apply a condition to each column) seems like a fundamental thing I should know how to do, so I would like to figure out how to do it this way.

Here is an example.  Imagine I have the following data frame:

```
row   A   B  C  D  E
1     3   5  6  9 -1
2    -1   3 -1  2  0
3    -1  -1 -1  1 -1
```

The output I would like to get would be:

```
A  B  C  D  E
2  1  2  0  2
```

I have tried the following:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x == -1).count() # value returned was the count of all the rows
(df == -1).count() # also returned a count of all the rows.
```

I looked through several questions related to "countif", but they all seemed to apply a condition to one column to select rows.  And the two items I tried above were from questions related to apply functions to each column and count values that match a condition in each column.

The suggested duplicate in the comments is looking for a single value for the entire dataframe and different criteria on each column.  I am looking to apply the same condition to every column and get a result per column, as shown in the selected answer below.

I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get dataframe row count based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322109/get-dataframe-row-count-based-on-conditions)

Comment: `df[df==-1].count()`

Comment: The `df[df==-1].count()` shown above also worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) + [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
#You can omit to_frame and T if you don't want a DataFrame.
df.eq(-1).sum().to_frame().T
#(df==-1).sum() #similar
```

or if it is `str`:

```
df.eq('-1').sum().to_frame().T
```

---

if row is a column:

```
df[df.columns[1:]].eq(-1).sum().to_frame().T

   A  B  C  D  E
0  2  1  2  0  2
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.eq(-1).sum()).T` to match OPs desired output

Comment: or `to_frame()`

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Since I had to go test this and make sure I understood it, I will add this for other newbies:  Without the .to_frame() it returns a series and the .T does a transpose (in my example I showed the values in a row and by default it returns a column)