# Pandas/python join/merge two dataframes on a column of list

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

Let's consider two dataframes : `Person` and `Movie` :

dataframe `Person`

```
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|   |    nconst |       primaryName |           primaryProfession |                          knownForTitles |
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 0 | nm0000103 |      Fairuza Balk |          actress,soundtrack | tt0181875,tt0089908,tt0120586,tt0115963 |
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 1 | nm0000106 |    Drew Barrymore | producer,actress,soundtrack | tt0120888,tt0343660,tt0151738,tt0120631 |
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 2 | nm0000117 |     Neve Campbell | actress,producer,soundtrack | tt0134084,tt1262416,tt0120082,tt0117571 |
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 3 | nm0000132 |      Claire Danes | actress,producer,soundtrack | tt0274558,tt0108872,tt1796960,tt0117509 |
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 4 | nm0000138 | Leonardo DiCaprio |       actor,producer,writer | tt0120338,tt0993846,tt1375666,tt0407887 |
+---+-----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

dataframe `Movie`

```
+---+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|   |    tconst | titleType |       originalTitle |                genres |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 0 | tt0192789 |     movie | While Supplies Last |        Comedy,Musical |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 1 | tt4914592 |     movie |      Electric Heart | Adventure,Drama,Music |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 2 | tt4999994 |     movie |           Rain Doll |                 Drama |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 3 | tt2690572 |     movie |             Polaris |                 Drama |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| 4 | tt1562859 |     movie |           Golmaal 3 |         Action,Comedy |
+---+-----------+-----------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

As you can see `knownForTitles` from `Person` is a list of `tconst` from `Movie` dataframe

Question :

1. How can I calculate "How many `actors` have ever acted in an `action` movie
2. How many actors are starring in more than one genre of movies?

Comment: none of the values in `tconst` match with `knownforTitles` , so this is not a minimum reproducible example, unless you provide data that matches, so it is not possible to do a `merge` without getting all `NaN`s with the current provided dataset. The only way to do a merge would be on the index, which I don't think would be correct here.

Comment: A meta question (I suppose):  How did you  format the  dataframes you put  into this question?  Also, is there an easy way for me to copy and paste your dataframes so I can use them to test my solution.  I've been using Excel to get them into .CSV format.

Comment: @DavidErickson, this is a small and example dataset and for this reason I explicitly stated that `knownforTitles` is the list consisting of `tconst`.

Comment: @Mark, I've used `https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables` to generate formatted dataframe. I was struggling to do this manually until I find this. BTW your format is also nice to visualize, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we create `person` as a DataFrame:

```
columns = ['nconst', 'primaryName', 'primaryProfession', 'knownForTitles',]

data = [
('nm0000103',      'Fairuza Balk',          'actress,soundtrack', 'tt0181875,tt0089908,tt0120586,tt0115963'),
('nm0000106',    'Drew Barrymore', 'producer,actress,soundtrack', 'tt0120888,tt0343660,tt0151738,tt0120631'),
('nm0000117',     'Neve Campbell', 'actress,producer,soundtrack', 'tt0134084,tt1262416,tt0120082,tt0117571'),
('nm0000132',      'Claire Danes', 'actress,producer,soundtrack', 'tt0274558,tt0108872,tt1796960,tt0117509'),
('nm0000138', 'Leonardo DiCaprio',       'actor,producer,writer', 'tt0120338,tt0993846,tt1375666,tt0407887'),
]

person = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

Second, we split strings into lists for two of the columns:

```
for field in ['primaryProfession', 'knownForTitles']:
    person[field] = person[field].str.split(',')
```

Third, we use the `explode` function to convert one row into many:

```
person = person.explode('knownForTitles').explode('primaryProfession')
```

Fourth, we select only actress/actor as the primary profession:

```
actor_actress = person[ person['primaryProfession'].isin(['actress', 'actor'])]
```

Now, we have a data frame in so-called tidy format (each cell has a single value, not a list):

```
    nconst     primaryName   primaryProfession knownForTitles
0   nm0000103  Fairuza Balk   actress          tt0181875
0   nm0000103  Fairuza Balk   actress          tt0089908
0   nm0000103  Fairuza Balk   actress          tt0120586
0   nm0000103  Fairuza Balk   actress          tt0115963
1   nm0000106  Drew Barrymore actress          tt0120888
```

At this point, we can repeat these steps for the Movie data frame, and then join actors (using knownForTitles) and Movies (using tconst).

Sorry for the length of this response.  Key points this approach are to use `str.split(',')` and then use `explode()` to transform the data frame into a format suitable for join, merge, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning pandas, so there's a good chance I'm going the wrong way with this.  That said, let's give this a go:

First, let's see if we can find all rows in df Movie that are action films.  Looking at [Pandas dataframe select rows where a list-column contains any of a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342715/pandas-dataframe-select-rows-where-a-list-column-contains-any-of-a-list-of-strin), I came up with this:

```
Movies['isAction'] = [ 'Action'  in x for x in Movies['genres'].tolist()  ]
```

Here's the result:

```
      tconst titleType      originalTitle                     genres  isAction
0  tt0407887     movie  WhileSuppliesLast          [Comedy, Musical]     False
1  tt1375666     movie      ElectricHeart  [Adventure, Drama, Music]     False
2  tt4999994     movie           RainDoll                    [Drama]     False
3  tt2690572     movie            Polaris                    [Drama]     False
4  tt0134084     movie           Golmaal3           [Action, Comedy]      True
```

I added the `isAction` column to the Movies df.  I also changed some of the `tconst` values so that we can get some positive results (rows 0,1, and 4 changed).

I changed `row 4` so that Neve Cambelle would appear in the results.

We can now produce a list of `tconst` of Action Movies:

```
 listOfActionMovies = Movies[ Movies["isAction"] == True]["tconst"].tolist()
```

Now using the solution from [Pandas dataframe select rows where a list-column contains any of a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342715/pandas-dataframe-select-rows-where-a-list-column-contains-any-of-a-list-of-strin) again:

```
Person["inAction"] = pd.DataFrame(Person.knownForTitles.tolist()).isin( listOfActionMovies ).any(1)
```

This yields:

```
      nconst       primaryName                primaryProfession                                knownForTitles  inAction
0  nm0000103       FairuzaBalk            [actress, soundtrack]  [tt0181875, tt0089908, tt0120586, tt0115963]     False
1  nm0000106     DrewBarrymore  [producer, actress, soundtrack]  [tt0120888, tt0343660, tt0151738, tt0120631]     False
2  nm0000117      NeveCampbell  [actress, producer, soundtrack]  [tt0134084, tt1262416, tt0120082, tt0117571]      True
3  nm0000132       ClaireDanes  [actress, producer, soundtrack]  [tt0274558, tt0108872, tt1796960, tt0117509]     False
4  nm0000138  LeonardoDiCaprio        [actor, producer, writer]  [tt0120338, tt0993846, tt1375666, tt0407887]     False
```

Now finally we can count all the `People` in action movies:

```
len(Person[ Person["inAction"] == True ])
```

`len()` solution provided by [get dataframe row count based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322109/get-dataframe-row-count-based-on-conditions).